# Change screen resolution from terminal

Tags: command-line, nvidia

When I enabled my Nvidia graphics card, it changed the resolution of my screen to larger than my screen. As the result I cannot access any functions that were previously on the right side of my screen. How do I undo this? I originally had 8.04 and was able to change the resolution to whatever I wanted.

I'm a new user and can copy and paste commands from a post to terminal mode but that's about it. I have no idea what they are or what they mean.

Comment: Can you give us the output of `xrandr` command ?

Answer (score 0):

Open Nvidia Settings, select Xserver Display Configuration, and change the resolution.  If it appears to be working correctly then click the button to save Xserver configuration.

You can start Nvidia Settings by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> (formerly the Windows key) and then typing 'nvidia settings' into the search bar, then click on the icon labelled 'NVIDIA X server settings.

Nvidia settings should get installed when you install one of the nvidia drivers, however if it did not then you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
```